# How and when to set mobx domain object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm having trouble finding a good solution to a particular problem in my react/mobx application. Let's say I have a number of boxes which I want to position on the screen in a certain layout in which the position of each box depends on the positions of all other boxes (think force directed layout or similar). There is also a re-layouting happening depending on some other `@observable` variables such as `sorting` by size of the box or `filtering` by category. In addition, the boxes are interactive and get `highlighted` if one is hovered with the mouse. I would also like this to be reflected in the boxes data as a `highlighted` property set on the boxes.

Coming from redux, my initial approach would have been to have some observable ui-state variables such as `sortBy` and `filterBy` and then have a `@compute` getter that returns a **fresh** array of **fresh** box objects with their `positions` and `highlighted` property set each time one of the variables changes.

```
const boxes = [{ id: '1', category: 'bla', size: 5 }, ...];

class UiStore {
    @observable sortBy = 'size';
    @observable filterBy = undefined;
    @observable hoveredBox = undefined;

    /* Some @action(s) to manipulate the properties */
}

const uiStore = new UiStore();

class BoxesStore {
    @computed
    get positionedBoxes() {
        const filteredBoxes = boxes.filter(box => 
            box.category === uiStore.filterBy
        );

        // An array of positions based on the filtered boxes etc.
        const positions = this.calculateLayout(filteredBoxes);
        return boxes.map((box, i) => {
            const { x, y } = positions[i];
            return {
                ...box,
                highlighted: uiStore.hoveredBox === box.id,
                x,
                y,
            };
        });
    }
}
```

In theory this works fine. Unfortunately I don't think this is the most efficient solution in terms of performance. With a lot of boxes, creating new objects on every change and on every hover can't be the best solution. Also according to the [mobx best practices](https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html) it is advised to think about the whole topic slightly differently. The way I understand it, in mobx you are supposed to create actual instances of boxes each having `@observable` properties themselves. Also one is supposed to only ever hold one instance of each box in the boxesStore. If I were for example to add an additional `@computed` getter that calculates a different kind of layout I'm now technically holding multiple versions of the same box in my store, right?

So I tried to find a solution with creating a `Box` class instance for each box item with an `@computed` getter for the `highlighted` property. This works, but I can't wrap my head around how and when to set the position of the boxes. One way would be to go with a similar approach to the one above. Calculating the positions in a `@computed` getter and then setting the x, y position of each box in that same function. This might work, but it definitely feels wrong to set the positions within a @compute.

```
const boxes = [{ id: '1', category: 'bla', size: 5 }, ...];

/* uiStore... */

class Box {
    constructor({id, category, size}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @computed 
    get highlighted() {
        return this.id === uiStore.highlighted
    }
}

class BoxesStore {
    @computed
    get boxes() {
        return boxes.map(box => new Box(box));
    }
    @computed
    get positionedBoxes() {
        const filteredBoxes = this.boxes.filter(box => 
            box.category === uiStore.filterBy
        );

        // An array of positions based on the filtered boxes etc.
        const positions = this.calculateLayout(filteredBoxes);

        const positionedBoxes = filteredBoxes.map(box => {
            const { x, y } = positions[i];
            box.x = x;
            box.y = y;
        })
        return positionedBoxes;
    }
}
```

A different approach would be to calculate all the positions in a @compute on boxesStore and then accessing these positions within the box.

```
const boxes = [{ id: '1', category: 'bla', size: 5 }, ...];

/* uiStore... */

class Box {
    constructor({id, category, size}, parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.size = size;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @computed 
    get position() {
        return _.find(this.parent.positionedBoxes, {id: this.id})
    }
}

class BoxesStore {
    @computed
    get boxes() {
        return boxes.map(box => new Box(box));
    }
    @computed
    get positionedBoxes() {
        const filteredBoxes = this.boxes.filter(box => 
            box.category === uiStore.filterBy
        );
        // An array of positions based on the filtered boxes etc.
        return this.calculateLayout(filteredBoxes);
    }
}
```

Again, this might work but it feels super complicated. As a last approach I was thinking about doing something with mobx reaction or autorun to listen to changes in the uiStore and then setting the position of the boxes via an action like so:

```
const boxes = [{ id: '1', category: 'bla', size: 5 }, ...];

/* uiStore... */

class Box {
    @observable position = {x: 0, y: 0};

    @action 
    setPosition(position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}

class BoxesStore {
    constructor() {
        autorun(() => {
            const filteredBoxes = this.boxes.filter(box => 
                box.category === uiStore.filterBy
            );

            this.calculateLayout(filteredBoxes).forEach((position, i) =>
                filteredBoxes[i].setPosition(position);
            )
        })
    }

    @computed
    get boxes() {
        return boxes.map(box => new Box(box));
    }
}
```

I like this approach the most so far but I don't feel like any of these solutions are ideal nor elegant. Am I missing some obvious approach to this type of issue? Is there a simpler and more practical approach to solving this?

Thanks for reading through all of this :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation of `calculateLayout` i would suggest either using `computed` or derived&observed position.

first of, instead of computing boxes i would keep this your observed data structure so classes don't need to be recreated on change:

```
class BoxStore {
  @observable
  boxes;
}
```

### case for computed.

If calculateLayout() simply just ups the coordinates with a set x and y based on the previous Box, i would suggest just using a linked list structure:

```
class Box {
  @observable prevBox;
  @computed 
  get position() 
    if(this.prevBox)
       return this.prevBox.clone().add(10,20);
    return {x:0,y:0};
  }
}
```

### Case for observed

If the computation is complex and only needs to be partially re-computed when boxes are added or removed i would suggest using property observer: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#observe

```
class BoxStore {
  @observable
  boxes = [];
  constructor(){
    mobx.observe(this.boxes, (change) => {
       // efficiently compute new locations based on changes here.
    })
  }
}
```

this way you have the advantage that it is not completely recomputed every time. but have the advantage that the position is still 'derived'. (you don't have to manully set it). once you got the formula right you never have to think about it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure though if I described my problem clear enough. I guess what my question boils down to is whether it is a bad idea to basically keep one static (not changing and no observable properties) array of data objects in the store and then create a new array of new objects inside computes every time some uiState changes. In my view this would conform to the mobx mantra of derriving everything that can be derrived from some simpler state representation but it might end up being computationally intensive.

Comment: @Flavio your Box class object list can be your simplest observable data object. Don't over simplify your data structure. only downside of class is that its harder to jsonify and send back to the server, thats why some prefer simple objects.